# Does jsoup support restful/rest request

Tags: rest, request, jsoup, http-delete, http-put

Can you tell me please how to create http(s) request in jsoup with request method PUT or DELETE?

I came across this link:
https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/158
but it is few years old, so hopefully there is some restful support implemented in that library.

As far as I can see HttpConnection object I can only use 'get' or 'post' request methods.

http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/helper/HttpConnection.html

http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsoup doesn't support PUT nor DELETE methods. Since it is a parser, it doesn't need to support those operations. What you can do is use `HttpURLConnection` , which is the same that Jsoup uses underneath. With this you can use whatever method you want and in the end parse the result with jsoup (if you really need it). 
Check this code :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String rawData = "RAW_DATA_HERE";
            String url = "URL_HERE";
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

            //add reuqest header
            con.setRequestMethod("METHOD_HERE"); //e.g POST
            con.setRequestProperty("KEY_HERE", "VALUE_HERE"); //e.g key = Accept, value = application/json

            con.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStreamWriter w = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");

            w.write(rawData);
            w.close();

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }

            in.close();

            System.out.println("Response code : " + responseCode);
            System.out.println(response.toString());

            //Use Jsoup on response to parse it if it makes your work easier.
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and explanation. I was aware of HttpUrlConnection approach but since jsoup supports GET,POST methods, I'd expect it to be able to process all methods for completeness.